# @RequestMapping not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/check")
public class Controller {

    public String index(){
        return "sdfksdjfkjkUshshdfisdfsdkasjdfjkasjdfkjakl:";
    }
```

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Added all the necessary dependency when running the application shows the

```
http://localhost:8081/demo/
Hello World
```

of index.xml

When I change to http://localhost:8081/check/ it gives

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /check

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

How can I understand the flow of Spring Boot application?

Comment: Unless you have an explicit mapping for /demo then /demo must be the context path of the deployed application.All other endpoints are the then relative to this context path i.e. http://localhost:8081/demo/check/

Comment: Try http://localhost:8081/demo/check because you annotated in class

Comment: @AlanHay I tried that but that doesnot work

Comment: Which package is your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in and in which your controller.

Comment: import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

Comment: You ned an `@RequestMapping` on the `index` method as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the Http method on your method, here I am assuming you are doing a `GET` request

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/check")
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping // you forgot to put http method here
    public String index(){
        return "sdfksdjfkjkUshshdfisdfsdkasjdfjkasjdfkjakl:";
}
```

---

Note: `GetMapping` is only available if you are using `Spring 4.3` or above else use `@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be like this:

```
@RestController  
public class Controller {
     @RequestMapping(value="/check")
      public String index(){
          return "sdfksdjfkjkUshshdfisdfsdkasjdfjkasjdfkjakl:";
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems
@RequestMapping(value="/check") is not working.

switch to
@RequestMapping(path="/check")

though as per documentation it should work.

Comment: Both are the same. `path` is an alias for `value`.